# XCTest output in console: how to clean up formatting?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xctest

We spent a bunch of time making clear and clean formatting for our own unit test harness. Then we switched to XCTest in Xcode. The output is just a terrible data dump in the Xcode console.

Is there:

1) Anyway to specify a format for XCTest?

2) A way to silence the output of XCTest and use our own functions?

3) A less verbose flag for XCTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcpretty can give your logs a cleaner more readable output and to take that further you can use Tee to pipe the verbose output to a log file

https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty